# What are benefits of having jenkins master in a docker container?

Tags: jenkins, docker, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, continuous-delivery

I saw couple of tutorials on continuous deployment ([on docker.com](https://www.docker.com/sites/default/files/RA_CI%20with%20Docker_08.25.2015.pdf), [on codecentric.de](https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2015/10/continuous-integration-platform-using-docker-container-jenkins-sonarqube-nexus-gitlab/), [on devopscube.com](http://devopscube.com/docker-containers-as-build-slaves-jenkins/)).

Overall I saw two approaches:

1. Set two types of jenkins server (master and slave). Master is in a docker container and slave on the host machine.
2. Jenkins server in docker container. They set up the link to the host and using that link the jenkins can create or recreate docker images.

In the first approach - I do not understand why they set up additional jenkins server residing inside the docker container. Is not it enough just to have jenkins server on host machine alongside with docker container?

The second approach seems to me a bit insecure because process from container is accessing host OS. Does it have any benefits?

Thanks for any useful info.

Comment: My idea/understanding of docker is to not mix containers with software on the host (except for tools like git for managing `docker-compose.yml` and other files). As for option 2: there is also Docker in Docker. And security depends on what you are using it for - just yourself, limited access or can everyone sign up and use your jenkins instance.

Comment: @mgansler I tried o have jenkins in docker and build other images using docker API from this jenkins container but somehow it was not able to execute the task (there are 2 executors free but it was not able to use them - the build was always in idle)